# What format does Cockpit need for local VM images?

Tags: linux, fedora, virtual-machine, cockpit

I am using Cockpit to stand up VMs on my Fedora 32 server (https://fedoramagazine.org/create-virtual-machines-with-cockpit-in-fedora/). I am able to stand up a VM without any issue if I use the option "Download an OS using Cockpit’s built-in library"; however, I need to standup both FreeNAS and Windows10 as VMs which are not provided in the links.

Right now I have set up vsftpd and am able to upload images from one of my other computers that have a GUI. I don't know what format they need to be in or how to make them...

I have tried both just uploading the .iso files to the server and have tried making a bootable media then uploading a clone of that drive to the server. Neither of those methods has worked...

If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be awesome or just tell me the format it needs to be in that would be nifty.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: `Creation of VM FreeNAS failed show less 
ERROR internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2020-04-30T14:54:59.961806Z qemu-system-x86_64: -blockdev {"driver":"file","filename":"/home/sysadmin/FreeNAS-11.3-U2.iso","node-name":"libvirt-1-storage","auto-read-only":true,"discard":"unmap"}: Could not open '/home/sysadmin/FreeNAS-11.3-U2.iso': Permission denied Domain installation does not appear to have been successful. If it was, you can restart your domain by running: virsh --connect qemu:///system start FreeNAS otherwise, please restart your installation.`

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue. I was trying to load the image from a user's directory under /home/ and that was causing the issue.

After I moved the .iso into /var/ everything started working perfectly fine. I was able to download .iso files and go to town.

This is the thread that helped me out: https://askubuntu.com/questions/687474/virt-install-internal-error-process-exited-while-connecting-to-monitor-symli